# How to bind a key event in Ruby Tk

Tags: ruby, tk-toolkit

I want to display in the console what I press in a Tk window.

I wrote the following code:

```
require 'tk'

root = TkRoot.new
entry = TkEntry.new(root) do
  pack
end

entry.bind("Key", proc {p "key pressed"})
Tk.mainloop
```

It displays `key pressed` if I press any key.

But I want to display the key I press, not a constant string. Who can help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe me. Change the binding to:

```
entry.bind("Key", proc{|k| p "key pressed #{k}"}, "%K")
```

Depending on the format, use either `%A` (ASCII code), `%K` (keysym name), or `%N`  (keysym number) as the last argument.

Answer (score 0):

I like sawa's reply; here is the copy/pasteable example:

```
require 'tk'

alias e puts

root = TkRoot.new
root.geometry('800x600+0+0')
entry = TkEntry.new(root) {
  pack
}
entry.bind('Key', proc {|this_key|
  e "This key was pressed: `#{this_key}`"
}, '%K')

Tk.mainloop
```